# Complete one field automatically

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing a php/mysql system in the UK.

I gather data for clients including their postcode (zipcode). I also want to enter the ward they live in. I have a table 'clients' which includes the fields 'postcode' and 'wardid' also a table 'wards' which has the fields 'wardid' and 'ward' and finally a table 'zipward' with the fields 'id' 'postcode' and 'wardid'.

On the page that gathers the basic info about the client, once I have entered their postcode I would like the 'ward' entry box to be automatically filled with the correct ward.

I have no idea how to do this. Can anyone assist please?

Comment: **StackOverflow** isn't a coding service. Please read [*How to Ask*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and include what you've tried so far in your question!

Answer (score 0):

This query should gave you the Ward related to the postcode:

```
SELECT WARD
FROM WARDS
INNER JOIN zipward USING(wardid)
WHERE postcode = $SelectedPostCode
```